# How to get quick answers in Google or DuckDuckGo using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, scrape, duckduckgo

I have an AI Assistant project and I want it to search in internet. I want to use Google Quick Answer Box or DuckDuckGo Instant Answer API for Python. I saw other questions but they didn't help me so much. Here is an example what I want to achieve:

Question: What is giraffe?

Google's Answer:

[image]

DuckDuckGo's Answer:

[image]

As you can see the answers start with,

> **'The giraffe is an African artiodactyl mammal...'**

How can I get this text using ***Python***? (let me say 'what is giraffe' is an example. i want to use this method almost everything like 'tell me president of united states' etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [duckduckgo API](https://duckduckgo.com/api) as suggested in the comments using :

```
GET https://api.duckduckgo.com?q=[your query]&format=json
```

Here is an example using [python](/questions/tagged/python) :

```
import requests

query = "What is giraffe?"

r = requests.get("https://api.duckduckgo.com",
    params = {
        "q": query,
        "format": "json"
    })

data = r.json()

print(data)

print("Abstract")
print(data["Abstract"])
```

Output:

> The giraffe is an African artiodactyl mammal, the tallest living
>   terrestrial animal and the largest ruminant. ..........